# React useImperativeHandle how to expose DOM and inner methods?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Very simple question, I need to use `useImperativeHandle` to expose internal child method to parents. 
But I also want to access ref.current.style for example, it's currently undefined when using `useImperativeHandle` any idea how to pass it with inner methods ?

```
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        someMethod: () => {
            ...
        },
        ...ref
    }));
```

The above would work but is it the right way to do it ? (also we would have to do ref.current.current which is not really nice)

An easy exemple:

```
function FancyInput(props, ref) {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    focus: () => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }));
  return <input ref={inputRef} ... />;
}
FancyInput = forwardRef(FancyInput);

function FancyParent() {
   const childRef = useRef()

   useEffect(()=>{
     childRef.current.style.opacity = 0;
     // oups current.style has been ovveriden and is now 
    //undefined
   })

   return <FancyInput ref={childRef}/>
}
```

Comment: Show proper example of code to demonstrate your issue. It's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: sorry the example is extremely simple I thought it was self explanatory, I added  simple example, let me know if it's more clear

Comment: It's okay. But I have not downvoted your question. Let me look at your question again so that I may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually overriding ref. You want to use like this:

```
function FancyInput(props, ref) {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    focus: () => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    },
    opacity: () => {
      inputRef.current.style.opacity = 0
    }
  }));
  return <input ref={inputRef} ... />;
}
FancyInput = forwardRef(FancyInput);

function FancyParent() {
   const childRef = useRef()

   useEffect(()=>{
     childRef.current.opacity()
   })

   return <FancyInput ref={childRef}/>
}
```

If you want to interact directly in FancyParent, then you'll need to use:

```
childRef.current.current.style.opacity = 0
```

Here, `childRef.current` indicates `ref` in the FancyInput. `ref.current.style` (ref==> childRef.current)

```
function FancyParent() {
   const childRef = useRef()
   const inputRef = childRef.current
   useEffect(()=>{
     inputRef.current.style.opacity = 0
   })

   return <FancyInput ref={childRef}/>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must note that `childRef` and `inputRef` are not the same. You can however expose `inputRef` from `childRef` with `useImperativeHandle`

```js
const  {useRef, useEffect, useImperativeHandle, forwardRef} = React;
let FancyInput = forwardRef((props, ref)  => {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    focus: () => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    },
    inputRef: inputRef.current,
  }));
  return <input ref={inputRef} style={{opacity: 1}}/>;
})

function FancyParent() {
   const childRef = useRef()

   useEffect(()=>{

     childRef.current.inputRef.style.opacity = 0;
   })

   return <FancyInput ref={childRef}/>
}


ReactDOM.render(<FancyParent/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Comment: I validated the first person to answer but thank you, very clear answer

Comment: Glad to have helped 

Comment: Just be careful about when `useImperativeHandle` runs. Assigning `ref.current` doesn't trigger a re-render, so if you were to assign a ref after a delay, `useImperativeHandle` won't run, so `FancyParent` won't know about it, unless there's a re-render: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-useimperativehandle-r9jgls?file=index.js